# Stuck on Chapter 5 or RoR Hartl's Tutorial Filling Out The Layout and static pages spec rspec errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I have been stuck on this for 3 days. I have probably read every thread on stackoverflow related to errors and Chapter 5, but can't seem to find a fix.

I keep getting this error

```
Failures:

  1) Static pages should have the right links on the layout
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector 'h1', text: 'Sample App'
       expected css "h1" with text "Sample App" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages About Page 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| About Us' }
       expected css "title" with text "| About Us" not to return anything
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages About Page it should behave like all static pages 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1', text: heading) }
       expected css "h1" with text "Sample App" to return something
     Shared Example Group: "all static pages" called from ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:39
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Static pages Home page 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home' }
       expected css "title" with text "| Home" not to return anything
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Static pages Contact Page 
     Failure/Error: it {should_not have_selector 'title', text:'| Contact Us'}
       expected css "title" with text "| Contact Us" not to return anything
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:51:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Static pages Contact Page it should behave like all static pages 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1', text: heading) }
       expected css "h1" with text "Sample App" to return something
     Shared Example Group: "all static pages" called from ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:50
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Static pages Help Page 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: ' | Help' }
       expected css "title" with text " | Help" not to return anything
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) Static pages Help Page it should behave like all static pages 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1', text: heading) }
       expected css "h1" with text "Sample App" to return something
     Shared Example Group: "all static pages" called from ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:28
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.36621 seconds
13 examples, 8 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:54 # Static pages should have the right links on the layout
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:40 # Static pages About Page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8 # Static pages About Page it should behave like all static pages 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19 # Static pages Home page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:51 # Static pages Contact Page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8 # Static pages Contact Page it should behave like all static pages 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:29 # Static pages Help Page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8 # Static pages Help Page it should behave like all static pages
```

I have checked my syntax in all relevant files, I have checked for any typos, especially double versus single quotes. because I have been looking at this for three days and have not found any good solutions either here or elsewhere, and I am unsure as to where exactly I may have gone wrong, instead of pasting code here , here is a link to my  app on github, latest working branch
thank you  for any help!
https://github.com/cassking/sample_app/tree/filling-out-layout

Answer (score 0):

I just cloned your github repository to my Mac, picked a Ruby version, ran `bundle instal` and successfully ran your test, as shown below.  What version of Ruby are you using?

```
new-host:stackoverflow_sample_app palfvin$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
1.9.3-p194 :001 > quit
new-host:stackoverflow_sample_app palfvin$ rspec spec/*
.........

Finished in 0.27565 seconds
9 examples, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 61309

new-host:stackoverflow_sample_app palfvin$ ls spec/*
spec/spec_helper.rb

spec/requests:
static_pages_spec.rb
new-host:stackoverflow_sample_app palfvin$
```

Comment: Hi, I am using ruby 1.9.3p194

Comment: How about Rails version? Also, you might try printing out the page/response after visiting the page, just to see what you've got.

Comment: Hi Peter, I am using Rails 3.2.13